# What considerations need to be made when transitioning an application to support?

Tags: c#, web-applications, sharepoint-2007, mvp

I will be taking on the role of support for a complex application that is transitioning from the development team. This application is a sharepoint solution that connects to several (7) web services. The development team is rolling off almost immediately and will be available only for small questions.

I'm new to this role so I'm wondering what suggestions you have for me as I take on this large project. What are some considerations that should be made so that the transition to support is smooth and uninterupted?

I've been reading the documentation but I can already see some gaps that need to be filled. The applicaiton is very (perhaps overly) configurable and there is lots of injected code. Stepping through the code is about the only way I can gain an understanding of what is actually happening.

Comment: Start reading http://thedailywtf.com/ every day. If you see any of the app's code there: run and run fast!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you've already got your environment set up if you're able to debug the application, so that's the first thing I was going to suggest in a knowledge-transfer situation.  Some general things that I would get from the developers before they depart:

1. A list of third-party components that the application uses, along with license information and website logins if applicable.
2. Access to every part of the environment that this thing runs on, both production and development.  That means the source code management system, database server(s), etc.  It sounds like you have some of these already but make sure you get access to absolutely everything.
3. If your development environment was given to you "as is" (i.e. you took it over from one of the departing developers, make sure you know how to rebuild it from scratch.  They might have a document that describes the process of building a development box, but if not maybe you can get them to show you how to set up a fresh machine.
4. Three will go a long way towards this, but if setting up a server to run the application is different in any way from setting up a development environment, you'd want to know how so you can diagnose server configuration issues if they crop up, or even rebuild a server.  Although this sort of thing may be someone else's responsibility depending on your organization.

Once you have those, you probably want to get some understanding of why the application does the things that it does.  That will give you the context you need to understand support and enhancement requests when they come in.

Are the original developers the only source of this information, or are there business people who you will be working with after the developers leave?  One of the first things I try to do when starting on an existing application that's new to me is to find someone who knows the business well and have them give me a high-level run-down of the application's purpose in life.  From there you can go into more detail on individual components/features/whatever as needed.  The business people may be a better source for this information than the developers are, so you may want to try them first.

Hopefully some of that helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not the systems admin (as opposed to the SharePoint admin), develop an understanding with them of what tasks you are able to do and what you need of them.

This may include things like stopping and starting services (IIS, Timer Service, etc.) and filesystem and DB monitoring and maintenance. Getting this sorted out up front saves a lot of pain later.

If the sys admins don't have some understanding of SharePoint, educate them. They will need to know what the deal is with things like code deployments.

It's best not to feel my pain.